# When do I give up on a tenured position at a T60~ math program?

Tags: graduate-admissions, tenure-track, industry

I am currently an undergraduate student applying to pure math PhD programs. I have been accepted to one of the seven schools which are tied for 20th on the [US News math graduate school rankings](https://www.usnews.com/best-graduate-schools/top-science-schools/mathematics-rankings) (At the time of writing this, the schools are CMU, GATech, JHU, UCSD, UIUC, UMD, and UofMN; I am aware that the US News rankings are highly flawed, but it is the best I have to go by). It may be worth noting that I am also currently attending one of these seven schools. At this point it looks like I will not be accepted anywhere better.

I understand that an acceptance to a T30 graduate program is a great achievment, and the particular program I've been accepted to has a good reputation and is also a solid fit for my current mathematical interests.

That being said, my plan for math grad school was to aim for academia & a tenured research position, with industry as a "back-up". Moreover, I would only be satisfied with a tenured research position at a T60~ school: I would rather be making more money in industry than to have a career as a mediocre mathematician. Based on what I have seen, the chances of me achieving this goal at one of the aforementioned schools is quite unlikely, unless I manage to do something very impressive. While I certainly have dreams of producing great results, I do not yet have enough experience doing research to know my capabilities and limitations.

In light of everything I've discussed, **should I enter graduate school with the expectation that I almost certainly will not get a tenure track position at a T60 math program?** If a career in academia at a "group 1" mathematics program is achieavable and not too unlikely, I am excited to work hard and put my nose to the grindstone, but I do not want to spend time towards an ultimately futile endeavor, especially when that time could be better spent preparing me for a job in industry. I would appreciate frank and honest insight into the chances of me achieving what I’m aiming for.

The field of mathematics which I plan on entering could not be farther from more "applicable" fields, like analysis/discrete math. It seems that it would be very wasteful to spend six years studying something I will never be able to use. Should I switch to studying something more applied now?

Comment: Why do you think that the ranking of the school you work at makes you a worse mathematician? Is it a virus or something? Why reject something now that wouldn't actually be an issue for over ten years?

Comment: @Buffy I assume you are referring to the line “mediocre mathematician”. I should clarify that I only meant mediocre as it concerns my position/status, not my actual innate abilities. In regards to your second question, I am not “rejecting” anything, my post is asking what the best course of action I should take is to maximize the utility of my graduate degree. I am worried that pursuing a PhD in a highly abstract field would be a waste at a non-T10 school, and that I should instead spend that time learning something which will make me more employable.

Comment: 'My post is asking what the best course of action I should take is to maximize the utility of my graduate degree.' Make your best guess and go with it. I doubt anyone here has the prophetic powers you hope for.

Comment: Being concerned about employability is certain reasonable. That said, to me your post reads more like you are highly concerned about prestige and are possibly using "employability"  as a way of rationalizing this concern. Incidentally, you did not improve your line about "mediocre mathematicians" by the reference to "innate abilities". A good lesson to learn is that no-one (other than possibly you yourself) cares about your "innate abilities", what people care about is the work that you do.

Comment: It seems like the part other people can help you with is a pretty easy math problem. How many of these jobs exist? How many people are potentially qualified for them (e.g., earn PhD degrees in math)? The hard part that no math will help you with is deciding whether that ratio is something you're comfortable with or not.

Comment: Adam, thank you for the response. I am not unwilling to admit that vanity is one of the reasons for my stated desires. Another reason is cultural — there is a difference in environment between a T60 math school and a small liberal arts school. My “T60 cutoff” is the point at which I believe the loss of prestige and the kind of mathematical environment I desire would make a higher paying industry job more attractive than academia. As it concerns “mediocre mathematician”, I guess I could clarify one last time: by mediocre I was referring only to prestige and status, as opposed to anything else.

Comment: I don't know any professors who were hyper fixated on "rankings," ever.

Comment: I think you should focus more on departments that have expertise in an area you're interested in and living surroundings that work best for you (for example, some people need to be in a large city with all sorts of cultural stuff available, and others (me, when younger) prefer lots of countryside and back roads for long distance runs and biking) and other such things than on nickel-and-diming rankings. **(continued)**

Comment: Your comment "*I do not want to spend time towards an ultimately futile endeavor*" sounds to me like math isn't really that much of a calling for you, so maybe you should consider a very applied subfield (e.g. computational mathematics) that would allow you to get a Ph.D. AND have the option of actually continuing to work at least roughly in your field in a non-academic job.

Comment: @Bryan I am aware that very few tenure track jobs exist. What I am also aware of is that the vast majority of these jobs go to people who did their PhD’s at a T10 program. I guess my question is: to what extent is this because T10 students are truly that much better, as opposed to bias in hiring practices? I can accept that academia is extremely competitive. What I’m trying to find out is the extent to which me going to a T30 vs a T10 school affects my chances, all else (ability, work ethic, etc.) being equal.

Comment: *trying to find out is the extent to which me going to a T30 vs a T10 school affects my chances* --- My guess is that most of this is due to selection bias for those who attend a top graduate program, which I suspect has been MUCH greater in the last 10-20 years (people often applying to over 10 programs; wider and easier availability of knowledge about programs) than it was 40-50 years ago (one rarely applied to more than 3 or 4 programs; word-of-mouth played a larger role; international presence/competition was much less in the U.S.).

Comment: "I am not unwilling to admit that vanity is one of the reasons for my stated desires." That's perfectly fine as a motivation if that's what you want to pursue. But I would still question your idea that as an undergraduate you have a decent idea of what mathematical culture looks like at different universities and that you have arrived at the number T60 through some rational process Like, how? Based on what? Where are you getting this information from about the difference between math culture at T60 and T160 schools from which you infer that T160 is too low for your preference?

Comment: It's of course ok to have an idea in your head of the kind of place you would or would not want to end up at, and you can be as demanding or as lenient about this as you like. What I am questioning is that you have correctly identified that this dividing line lies at T60 rather than T90 or T160 or T220 (or indeed that it lies on the T-something line at all). You say: "there is a difference in environment between a T60 math school and a small liberal arts school" Sure, and it's fine if you don't want to end up at a slac, but the slac category does not at all line up with "over/below T60".

Comment: @AdamPřenosil - I took the OP to mean "a department with a PhD program that averages more than 0.5 theoretical mathematics PhD graduates a year who go on to a research-oriented postdoctoral position (say teaching at most 13 semester credits per year)".  The number 60 is about right.

Comment: I find this post offensive. I am not at a T-60 school, but I am surrounded by very good mathematicians and I would venture the claim that they are all enjoying their job as much as I do. If you call everyone of us "mediocre", you're probably going to have a hard time in this profession and you shouldn't expect much sympathy. I will point out that people go to whatever school they are at not *only* because of their abilities; they take jobs because these jobs are close to spouses, family, or simply because they want to live in a specific part of the world. For most, ranking isn't that important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really doesn't matter too much what graduate school you go to - you will have to do something very impressive to get a tenure-track position (and eventually tenure) in theoretical mathematics at a Top 60 mathematics department.  It's true that people who go to the very top programs are more likely to do something very impressive, both because they are on average more likely to be very talented to begin with, and because they are also surrounded by more talented people.

The history of the job market is that every economic downturn makes the job market temporarily a lot worse, after which it recovers, but to a worse level than before.  Also, philosophy, and literature are good bellwethers for the theoretical mathematics job market; the theoretical mathematics job market always looks like (up to some adjustments for the economic cycle) what those job markets looked like 10-15 years ago.  Right now, philosophers and literature scholars simply tell people considering grad school not to go, and they all regret not having given that blanket advice 15-20 years ago.  Scholars in those fields are actively debating which philosophers and writers they should stop studying since there aren't enough jobs around for every important historical figure to actually be the subject of research.

If your second postdoc ends in the middle of a recession or pandemic a decade from now, you're only going to get hired if you're at least a longshot Fields Medal candidate.

There are plenty of startups out in Silicon Valley willing to pay you $120K a year - to start - it might be double that when you have enough experience - to write code.  If you care about money and don't mind being a bit bored and possibly working on some shady things (does anyone anymore think that Facebook - or even Stackexchange - has their users' interests at heart?) go do that.  (No - don't go into an applied math program either - just go take the money.)

Comment: Thank you for the response. If I understand correctly, you are saying that, as it concerns getting a job in academia, the school you go to does not matter nearly as much as the quality of your work, is that correct? My question is then: why do such a disproportionate number of professors at group 1 math programs have degrees from the top ten programs? Are grad students at these schools really that much stronger than those at slightly less prestigious schools? I must admit this feels unlikely to me, especially given how sharp the disparity in hiring is. Please correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: Most students ta top ten programs also don't get a job at group 1 math programs either.  Keep in mind that the job market is winners-take-all - there is no difference between being slightly worse than the cutoff needed to get a job and much worse than that cutoff.  What's happening is that cutoff is already substantially - say 1 standard deviation - above average at a top school, which means it's at the exceptional point - 2 or 3 standard deviations - for a non-top school.  Normal distributions have pretty skinny tails.

Comment: Let's suppose there are only 2 graduate programs A and B, abilities at each are normally distributed, with the distribution at A shifted one deviation stronger than the distribution at B.  If the cutoff was that the average student at A got a job, then 50% of A students would get a job and 32% of B students would get a job, so about 61% of jobs would be held by A students.  But if the cutoff is that the +1 SD student at A gets a job, then 32% of A students get a job and only 4.5% of B students get a job, meaning 87% of jobs are held by A students.  And at +2 SDs,  95% A students.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate this explanation. It is a relief to hear that academia is more meritocratic than I feared that is was not.

Comment: I think the takeaway should be that all situations with low success rates look unfair no matter how selection is done - maybe even that low success rates are unfair, period.